# Find User Property associated to an Firebase Event

Tags: firebase

I integrated firebase to my android and iOS app.

Whenever a User logs in to my app, I invoke

`analytics.setUserProperty(userId)`

When that piece of code executes, i can see the log (on Android)

`Setting user property (FE): _id, 58ca97a9f556b7300e8128da`

But how do I see this value on my firebase dashboard? I have a lot of Events with parameters being logged. But I don't see this user property associated with events anywhere.

I was under the assumption that user property is just like a event parameter except that they are persisted through the entire session. Is that not the case? If not, how do I query against them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Identify user who triggered the event use following methods, make sure you do not pass any PII data here, just pass user id which can be mapped with user id in your database.

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).setUserId(YOUR_USER-ID);
```

and to filter all events triggered by a user, you can use user property

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).setUserProperty("user_id", user.getUserId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a solution for this problem? 
I'm right now logging user id as an event parameter to get this information, but this is not very efficient.